# Passing String to JSNI

Tags: java, javascript, gwt

I'm having problem passing String to JSNI method:

```
public Wave() {
    initWave("wave_id");
}
```

**Doesn't work:**

```
public native void initWave(String id)/*-{
var instance = this;
var waveform = $wnd.Waveform({
    container: $doc.getElementById(id),
    data: [1, 0.2, 0.5]
    });
}-*/;
```

**Works:**

```
public native void initWave(String id)/*-{
var instance = this;
var waveform = $wnd.Waveform({
    container: $doc.getElementById("wave_id"),
    data: [1, 0.2, 0.5]
    });
}-*/;
```

I'm not sure why the string is not passed to the JSNI method.

Comment: did you try var id instead of String id.

Comment: The syntax you have already tried ought to work, try using a different parameter name - maybe `id` is clashing with something inside the GWT magic.

Comment: it works now I had to use __id instead of id, it seems you are right @IanRoberts